# Conflict between freefem++ and fglrx

Tags: package-management, 14.10, fglrx

I am trying to install the package `freefem++` via command-line and I stumble upon a strange conflict. Indeed `freefem++` is a finite element solver for PDE and I can't see why it wants to remove my graphics driver `fglrx`.

```
sudo apt-get install freefem++
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  freeglut3 libcr0 libhwloc-plugins libhwloc5 libibverbs1 libopenmpi1.6 libtorque2 ocl-icd-libopencl1
Suggested packages:
  blcr-dkms libhwloc-contrib-plugins opencl-icd
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  fglrx fglrx-amdcccle fglrx-core
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  freefem++ freeglut3 libcr0 libhwloc-plugins libhwloc5 libibverbs1 libopenmpi1.6 libtorque2 ocl-icd-libopencl1
0 upgraded, 9 newly installed, 3 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 6 093 kB of archives.
After this operation, 264 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n
Abort.
```

I still have the ability to install it from source but I'd rather use the repo.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

EDIT:

On topic again, I did what you advised and just two packages were lost : `libhwloc-plugins` and `ocl-icd-libopencl1`. Can I proceed without any further worry ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try removing the fgrlx, installing the freefem and then reinstalling the fgrlx.